# Can we extract image metadata from image after uploading in server using python?

Tags: python, django

I want to know the image properties like image pixels and dpi etc after uploading image in server using Python language. what is the best possible approach/technique to use.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do some research; then try for yourself. If you're stuck with a _specific_ problem, then ask about how to resolve it; this question is too broad.

Comment: I have researched on this. Python has Pillow library which extract metadata from image. Now problem is Pillow library don't extract metadata on some images like screenshots etc. So I am stucked at which approach should i use from where i can extract metadata from every image even if it is screenshot or scanned etc. Seeking your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tryout the library `pillow`, formerly known as `PIL`: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html

It allows you to open an Image and do operations on them or read properties. Maybe it will cover your use cases.

Example:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
width, height = im.size
dpi = YOUR_FUNCTION_FOR_DPI()
```

Comment: Thanks Özer S,  i tried this and it worked perfectly on the image which contains metadata. Now one question are there any images which don't contain metadata so if there are such images than how to extract data from such images?

Comment: i am afraid, is the image does not contain metadata, then pillow will only offer those that it can caluclate like width and height. Other metadata like where the picture was taken (geo location) etc. will be impossible for pillow to find, unless its in the metadata.

Comment: Thanks for helping. The solution which i thought is we can set random values if metadata is not available.

Comment: Yeah people usually down vote  question which they think is shitty besides they should know one who is asking is lay at his knowledge level. But You really saved my life. Thanks.